# Agrupar GridView por la primer columna

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo un GridView que muestra la siguiente información
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Como puedo hacer para mostrar agrupada por la primer columna es decir mostrar

Primer Bimestre
Materia - Nota

Segundo Bimestre
Materia - Nota

Esto lo estoy haciendo en ASP.NET Y VB.NET

Gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Comment: lo que quieres es que en la table te muestre  Periodo y despues enseguida de ella nota?

Comment: Así es Simon, Periodo y abajo la materia y la nota.

Comment: ya mirastes en la configuracionde ese componente?